# NSDateFormatter: set a minimum date valid

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdate

I'm trying to set a limit for what dates the user can enter into a textfield. Is there a way to set a minimum date for `NSDateFormatter` so that `getObjectValue` returns `NO` for a date before my specified minimum date? I am about to subclass `NSDateFormatter` and put this validation in myself, but was hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

NSDateFormatter doesn't specify a way for you to set the minimum/maximum dates for the user input(Unlike NSNumberFormatter).  So I think subclassing it would be appropriate, which shouldn't be too hard.  All you have to do is create a NSDateFormatter subclass, change the `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` method and apply the date checking of your minimum date.